# Anomalistic periods of Earth and Mercury

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion

Can any one give me a TRUE VALUE for the anomalistic periods of Earth and Mercury?

I note the [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/446087) on the following.

I more or less implemented the method suggested above using elliptic integrals, but the results I got seems a little off. For Earth, I get 365.30 days.

Comment: For Earth, Encyclopedia Britanica says the [anomalistic year](https://www.britannica.com/science/anomalistic-year) is 365 days 6 hours 13 minutes 53 seconds

Comment: Many thanks. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Do keep in mind that the orbit of Earth is not simply an ellipse in a Schwarzschild metric. It is perturbed by gravity from Jupiter, and other effects.